# Collection of Interfaces to pick from, Java

Tags: java

Consider that object wrapped in `DataContainer` will be handed out to client

```
// Will be handed out
public interface DataContainer
```

In order to use it, client currently needs to know to cast the object to:

```
public interface ConcreteObject_1_Container extends DataContainer
public interface ConcreteObject_2_Container extends DataContainer
```

Is it possible to offer both `ConcreteObject1Container` and `ConcreteObject2Container` as options to be chosen from, similar to how `Enum` options can be picked?

**Instead of** user magically knowing to use `FileContainer`

```
                                   // user knows
FileContainer   fileContainer   = (FileContainer) 
                ContainerFactory.getContainerFor(DataSource.FILE, 
                                                 TREAT_AS_SOURCE);
```

**I'd like to**

```
                                  // user selects
FileContainer   fileContainer   = (GenericContainer.FileContainer) 
                ContainerFactory.getContainerFor(DataSource.FILE, 
                                                 TREAT_AS_SOURCE);
```

Comment: Is there any third implementation to `DataContainer`? If no, there is no need to know the implementation, you can put all the methods the client needs in the interface.

Comment: Good question. "No" The only purpose for `DataContainer` is to serve as return type from `getContainerFor` method. However, `ConcreteObject1Container` lists method with concrete return type `A` and `ConcreteObject2Container` lists methods with concrete return type `B`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably change your design. Either:

1. the client just uses the methods on `DataContainer`, without caring what implementation it is, in which case the cast can be avoided, or
2. the client is actually coupled to the implementation, so should just use the implementation types directly (e.g. with two different methods)

Answer (score 0):

If you can make getConatainerFor a generic method, then it will be able to return the specific type using type inference.

Comment: A method can have 1 return type and that type is `GenericContainer`